# Ler imagem JPEG, convertê-la em PDF e salvar no disco - Visual Basic 6

Tags: c#, sql, visual-basic-6

Vou criar um botão, o qual ao clicá-lo, ele leia uma  imagem JPEG e possa convertê-la em PDF e salvar no disco.

Gostaria de uma dica em código-fonte para que eu possa iniciar este projeto.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: [`Console.WriteLine("Veja como fazer uma boa pergunta em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help");`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Dica: primeiro escolha a linguagem que vai usar, se VB ou C# (você marcou a pergunta com ambas).

Comment: Será em C#. .net.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta a seguir provém da fonte [Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/15/02/c_jpgpdf.htm).
Copiei integralmente para atender como resposta ao autor da pergunta, *inclusive, caso o link saia do ar*.

```
public void ImagensParaPDF(string ImagemCaminhoOrigem, string caminhoSaidaPDF)
{
    string[] caminhoImagens = GetImageFiles(ImagemCaminhoOrigem);

    if (caminhoImagens.Length > 0)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
        this.progressBar1.Maximum = caminhoImagens.Length;
        string pdfpath = caminhoSaidaPDF + ImagemCaminhoOrigem.Substring(ImagemCaminhoOrigem.LastIndexOf("\\")) + ".pdf";

        if (File.Exists(pdfpath))
        {
            pdfpath = SetNewName(caminhoSaidaPDF, ImagemCaminhoOrigem.Substring(ImagemCaminhoOrigem.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
        }

        using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfpath, FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();

            foreach (var item in caminhoImagens)
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(item);

                //image.SetAbsolutePosition(30f, 30f);
                if (this.chkScalebyImageSize.Checked)
                {
                    image.ScaleToFit(doc.PageSize.Width - 60, doc.PageSize.Height - 60);
                }
                else
                {
                    image.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(doc.PageSize.Height - 60);
                    image.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(doc.PageSize.Width - 60);
                }
                doc.Add(image);

                if (this.progressBar1.Maximum <= caminhoImagens.Length)
                    this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Imagem não encontrada.", "Pare!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

A função acima faz uso do **[iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)**, uma biblioteca de PDF que permite que você crie, adapte, inspecione e mantenha documentos no formato **PDF - Portable Document Format**.
Algumas [fontes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365986/documentation-for-itextsharp):

- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/iTextSharpTutorial.aspx)
- [Chapters](http://blog.rubypdf.com/itextsharp/tutorial01/)

---

Neste [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642280/jpg-to-pdf-convertor-in-c-sharp/1642290#1642290) (do próprio Stackoverflow) também trata desta mesma necessidade.